# Click on phonenumber need to go to dialog where user can select my application

Tags: android, dialog, contacts

**Use case:**

1. The user need to go to the default contact app
2. The user selects a user
3. The user clicks on phonenumber
4. The user gets a dialog and can choose my application

**Question**

My question is about step 4. What do i need to implement that functionality (maybe a intent filter)?

edit1: update manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="********"
          android:versionCode="26"
          android:versionName="1.0.11">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="10"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <!-- temporary for contact call -->

    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
            android:required="true"/>

    <application
            android:name=".AppContext"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
                android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".ui.WebviewActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.InCallActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to add intent filters with action ACTION_DIAL/ACTION_CALL to one of your Activities.

Intent-filter for Native Phone app Dialer Activity:

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="voicemail" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!--
         This was never intended to be public, but is here for backward
         compatibility.  Use Intent.ACTION_DIAL instead.
    -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.phone.action.TOUCH_DIALER" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: That is what you want when you want to call from your application to the default dialer right? I want the other way around. From default contact list to my app. (my application can call over wifi)

Comment: Yes. The intent action that is mostly fired when a phone number is clicked.

Comment: Oke but how can i listen to that? I want to get the users to my dial screen instead of the default. Can you give a example of that?

Comment: i just added your code to my manifest, but it did not work :( I updated my question with the current manifest.

Comment: Edited my answer. Also, note that if there is a default app set for ACTION_DIAL intent, the system would deliver it to that app only.

Comment: That did not work either. In my phone i get a option to call with skype or the default phone app. But not with my app.

Comment: Check the open source Android phone app in the link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/android-4.3_r3.1

Answer (score 0):

It works now with this code:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.InCallActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In the android guidelines they say not to use call_privileged, but their is not another good option at the moment.